# Is there a way to set up a trigger for when I receive an email?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am messing with a script that checks for messages with a certain tag in my email inbox and does a certain action.

Currently, the script works wonderfully, but I am having problems setting the trigger efficiently, right now it just searches the inbox every 15 min, but **I want it to look for emails only when is there really a new email**.
Is there a way to do that? Will it be more efficient to set a trigger like that or something different? (I am not sure of how much pressure or how many scripts can I execute before google says no more)

I am a rookie, so any help, even the most basic one, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a trigger like that, but you can try to set your timer to 1 or 5min? About quota, check the limit here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have learned a lot, it seems like a logical feature that is simply not there. Is there a way to get the suggestion to the google scripts team?